# Nested Queries? -> Set Value = (Select Value From OtherTable WHERE) 

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm looking to do a single query to update a database.  Here is some pseudocode:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.Value = (SELECT Value FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id==2) WHERE Table1.Id == 4
```

Comment: Looks OK to me apart from the == , provided the inner select picks only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if your subquery `(SELECT Value FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id=2)` only returns one value.  Also replace the `==` with `=` in your subquery as I have.

I believe updating it to what I have below would make it work no matter what:

`(SELECT Top (1) Value FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id=2)`

Comment: If by "would make it work" you mean "would silently pick one value arbitrarily" then, yeah sure.

Comment: Yeah... That's what I meant.  I'm impressed you could point that out though.  Give yourself a pat on the back.